# Making a field empty in mysql for one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Assume I have the following in my users table:

```
id     name     email
'1', 'foo', 'foo@bar.com'
'2', 'foo2', 'foo2@bar.com'
'3', 'foo3', 'foo3@bar.com'
'4', 'foo4', 'foo4@bar.com'
```

**Question 1)**

If I want to delete a column data for one of the fields. Is it safe if I set it to NULL (Please see the following update query in my example); in other words is it safe for all data types in mysql (int, varchar, bit,...) to assign NULL to make it empty?

```
UPDATE users
SET email = NULL
WHERE id = 3;
```

The above update query empties email field for user with id 3, but please confim this is the valid solutoin for all datatypes...

**Question2)**

After making the email field empty for user with id of 3 the following query is returning nothing:

```
select * from users where email is  NULL
```

Am I doing something wronmg here?

Please let me know if you need more clarification if the question is vague...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If NULL is allowed for the column in the table definition, then you can set NULL to any data type. Your code should work. What happens when you run "select * from users" in a command line or use a database manager?

Comment: `select * from users` returns all of the users; however `select * from users where email is  NULL` returns nothing!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE users
SET email = ''
WHERE id = 3;

Comment: Also when you search records for NULL or blank the safest way is          select * from users where email IS NULL or email IN('')